# Learn Python the Hard Way ex40 typing error

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I don't get how my code doesn't run from Powershell. It's giving me this error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex40.py", line 12, in <module>
    "So I'll stop right here"])
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

This is my code:

```
class Song(object):
    def _init_(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print line

happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you",
                   "I don't want to get sued",
                   "So I'll stop right here"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around the family",
                        "With pockets full of shells"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()
bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

I see in the book and other exact copies and the look all the same to mine(at least I think), but theirs is able to run.

Comment: I believe constructors are defined with two underscores rather than one: `def __init__(self)` or is that typo?

Comment: Thanks, yes it was a typo